# how to fit two figures into one column

Tags: floats, two-column

Ho, my code is this and it is placing figures in center using ieee 2-column format. I want to fit these figures in one column.

```
 \documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{floatrow}
    %\DeclareFloatSeparators{Qquad}{\hskip4em}
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \section{First section}
    \lipsum[1-2]
    
    \section{Second section}
    \lipsum[3]
    \begin{figure*}
    
    %\floatsetup{floatrowsep=Qquad}
    \begin{floatrow}
      \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{bbbbbbbbb} }{\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}}
      
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{vvvvvvvvvvv}}{\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}}
    
    \end{floatrow}
    \end{figure*}
    \lipsum[4]
    
    \section{Last section}
    \lipsum[5-10]
    
    \end{document}
```

the two figures are shown in image. I want them in red circle area in one column

[image]

Comment: just use the the same table I gave you in the previous question/ answer -- instead of text use `\includegraphics`

Comment: sorry didnt understand what you mean as i am already using \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(updated my answer after OP clarified that the graphs should be placed side by side, rather than one above the other)

You may be overthinking things. Just use a `figure` rather than a `figure*` environment, don't employ the machinery of the `floatrow` package, encase the graphs and their `\caption` statements in `minipage` environments of width `0.475\columnwith`, and replace `[scale=0.4]` with `[width=\linewidth]`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{lipsum,graphicx}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}
\lipsum[1-2]
\section{Second section}
\lipsum[3-4]

\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.475\columnwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{bbbbbbbbb}
\end{minipage}\hfill % maximize horizontal separation
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.475\columnwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
  \caption{vvvvvvvvvvv}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[5-6]
\section{Last section}
\lipsum[7-8]

\end{document}
```